# Editing Javascript for Vista Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, windows-vista, menu

I generated drop down menus for my site in Vista Buttons. When it exports the buttons, they are in a .js file along with graphics files and .css to control everything.

I did some extensive editing on the .css, and then decided to change all the .html extensions for the links that the menus are pointing to, to .php, because I am now using "includes" for the menus on every page on the site.

I went into the .js file to change all the targets to .php, changed them all, and when I load my site, they STILL SAY .HTML!!!

How can that be?
None of the files that are related even have a .html inside they anywhere!!!

Yes, I am referencing the correct files!

Amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser cache?  Try ctrl + F5 to force-reload.